# Is it possible to run in Ubuntu an application installed under Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04

Suppose I have installed an application (e.g. statistical software SAS 9.2 or 9.3) under Windows 7 on an ntfs partition. My Ubuntu 12.04 is installed on another ext4 partition. From ubuntu, I can see the partition where the application is installed via mounting it. Is it possible to run the application under Ubuntu? How is it done then? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can run it by emulating the `wine`.

For install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
```

Syntax:

```
$ wine /path/to/application.exe
```

Wine [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

Comment: Thanks! What kinds of possible problems will I run into?\

Answer (score 2):

As in the previous answer, you can run Windows applications with a variable amount of success using Wine. A list detailing the extent of compatibility can be found at the [website](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

You can not run the application from where it is currently installed on your Windows partition. A discussion on this can be found at the [Ubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116384/can-i-run-ms-office-apps-installed-under-windows). You will need the installation media to install the software in Ubuntu using Wine.

You might have problems running SAS in Wine according to their [compatibility ratings](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3410). After less than stellar results with MS Office in Wine or Crossover for Linux, I started using a hardware virtualization solution (Virtualbox to be precise). This was relatively easy to set up and is something you may want to explore. I eventually weaned myself off the dual boot I'd employed for years.

Edit: The final option you may want to consider is a either a Linux version of one of the statistical analysis packages (SPSS produce a version) or a free version such as [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/). I can't comment on the quality of the latter, but I've heard good things.